# How do i transfer multiple variables to a php page using <a href

Tags: php, html

Here is the code I am using.

```
<a href="delete_ac.php?id=<? echo $rows['id'];?>">delete</a></td>
```

Basically I want to send the table it came from to:

```
<a href="delete_ac.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']"; 
table=<? echo $tbl_name>">delete</a></td>
```

Comment: Just add an `&` ampersand between the variables, ie `<a href="delete_ac.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id'] ."&table=".$tbl_name; ?>">delete</a></td>`

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check these codes!

**This is the first code:**

```
<a href="delete_ac.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">delete</a></td>
```

**And the second code:**

```
<a href="delete_ac.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>&table=<?php echo $tbl_name; ?>">delete</a></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this : with the `&` operator

```
<a href="delete_ac.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id'];?>&table=<?php echo $tbl_name; ?>">delete</a>
```

- First parameter : `?`
- The next ones : `&`

Comment: Should be quoted: `...&amp;table=...`

Comment: @coudy No, if you are trying to display it, yes, but in a link when separating variables, putting it like that would cause it to not function properly.

Comment: @Jon Anywhere that `&` appears in HTML represents an entity, including in an attribute. So @coudy is correct, it should be `?id=foo&amp;bar=baz`. This is a common error highlighted by HTML validators.

Comment: @IMSoP You are right, [here's a source](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp) for what you said. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Correction

```
<a href="delete_ac.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']"; ?>
&table=<? echo $tbl_name;?>">delete</a></td>
```

Comment: Falsification: *<a href="delete_ac.php?id=<? echo **$rows['id']";** ?>*

Comment: Falsification?  What on earth do you mean?  This is a good example of how to do it. Granted there is a typo in there, but that's it.

Comment: @Jon Agreed.. I just want to mention the typo on her *“Correction”*. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/falsification

Comment: @Servant "I think you have a typo/mistake" would have been a clearer (and more polite) comment.

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, it's more polite comment.. But it doesn't mean that I want to be rude. I'd just searched *“opposite of correction”* in **Google**.

Comment: @Servant Ahh, obviously english isn't your first language then.  'Falsification' means to purposefully mislead someone.  ie telling someone that the sky is green when knowing that it is not.  'Falsification' doesn't cover typo's or small mistakes. ^^

Comment: @Jon Yes, for I'm a Filipino. I just want to make fun.. According to http://www.thefreedictionary.com/falsification *“Noun 1. falsification - **any evidence** that helps to establish the falsity of something”*.